# Windows Azure Active Directory Account + Office 365 + Windows 8 App Sign In Issue?

Tags: azure, windows-8.1, office365, azure-active-directory

I create a Windows Azure Active Directory(WAAD) Account and then by using this account I Create my Windows 8.1 Account for login.

Then I create a Windows 8.1 app and use the same account for getting data from my office 365 of share point, exchange and Active Directory User

You will see the sample here

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Office-365-APIs-Get-41eebcdf#content

I open the app click log in to the app by using my WAAD Account and get the data

**Now I want that If i am already logged in to Windows 8.1 using the same WAAD Account Then I automatically log in to Windows 8.1 App. please gave me directions or any sample i will move forward on my own 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By logging in to Windows 8.1 using a Azure AD account - I believe you mean: Signed-in to a domain joined Windows 8.1 device as a domain user, where the AD domain is connected to an Azure Active Directory via an ADFS server (federated domain of an Azure AD).

If so, yes you can "silently" sign-in the logged in domain user by using the extension grant OAuth flow supported by Azure AD. Flow details: your client application will use windows integrated auth to authenticate the user at on-premises ADFS, get a SAML1.1 token addressed to Azure AD, use the extension grant OAuth flow of Azure AD to exchange the SAML1.1 token for a JWT access token.

Fortunately you don't need to code that complicated flow yourself - Active Directory Auth Library v2 RC release does it for you. Vittorio has written a blog post about it here: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/10/adal-v2-and-windows-integrated-authentication/

Hope this helps.